# Grouping data that follows sequence N+1 in R

Tags: r

So i have a dataset that has three columns: position, time and intensity. The intensity is full of binary values, that i have filtered to just include 1's (as this represents the object of interest, whereas 0 is background).

I need a way to be able to group the data into sequences that follow N+1; refer to the image below.

[Snapshot of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIEjm.png)

As you can see, the first column goes from 4 to 22 in increments of 1 before skipping to 39, there are many such cases in my dataset (each skip represents the end of one object and the start of another) is there a way to find the positions of the numbers that follow the sequence N+1 and then group that into a variable thus allowing me to identify where each object is.

EDIT//

Following the reply i used the code and it produced this, it has produced another column (called T2) with numbers in:

```
structure(list(pixel_pos = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 39L), 
    Time_point = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Intensity = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), T2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Is there a way to group all the numbers in T2 that follow 1,2,3 etc.. as these represent the objects. Thanks again!

//EDIT 2
Original table, with no filtering (0's present)

```
Pixel_pos = 1:40, 
Time_point = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
Intensity = c(0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), 
row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "group all the numbers in T2 that follow 1,2,3 etc.. as these represent the objects." I thought `T2` was what you wanted. If that's not the case, could you please show what you do want?

Comment: Im sorry I should have been more clear, so as of right now my data has been filtered using filter(variable, Intensity == 1) and so none of the 0 intensity values are present. I was hoping there would be a way to ensure the variables assigned in T2 to each pixel position would persist even after intensity values of 0 return to the table, for graph plotting sake. If i tried to apply the function you suggested when the pixels with intensity 0 are present i dont think it would work. So i was wondering if there was a away to save the allocation and then merge it later with the complete table.Thanks

Comment: That's really hard to answer without seeing any of the data with `intensity = 0`.

Comment: I have attached another edit, really appreciate any help you can provide. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways, here are two (calling your data `df`):

```
df$group = as.integer(factor(df$first_column - 1:nrow(df)))

df$group = cumsum(c(1, diff(df$first_column) > 1))
```

If you run into trouble with these or need more help, please share a bit of your data in a reproducible way - pictures of data are difficult to work with. `dput(df[1:20, ])`, for example, gives a copy-pasteable version of the first 20 rows of your data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i have added an edit to the post

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand well your question, **and without a reproducible example it is really difficult to help**.

Anyway, I'll provide a data.table solution:

### Dummy data

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:100, y = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE, prob = c(.3, .6)))
```

Then we:

```
dt[, id := rleid(y)][, startPos := ifelse(id != shift(id, 1), 1, 0)][y == 1 & startPos == 1, ]
```

### What is in there:

- `id := rleid(y)`: we create a new variable `id` that has the run-length ids of variable y, that is, the continuous runs of it, very close to what you want.
- `startPos := ifelse(id != shift(id, 1), 1, 0)`: We create a new variable `startPos` that will have a 1 if the `id` is different from the next one (thus marking the starting position of such id).
- Finally we filter the results for those that have `y == 1` (your data of interest) and `startPos == 1` (the starting positions). `dt` still has all the original data.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with `dplyr`, we can simplify this a lot with the `lag` function. This is particularly helpful because we can set a default value for the first row.

```
library(dplry)
data %>% 
  mutate(T2 = cumsum(pixel_pos - lag(pixel_pos, default = 0) > 1))
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   pixel_pos Time_point Intensity    T2
       <int>      <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
 1         4          1         1     1
 2         5          1         1     1
 3         6          1         1     1
...
18        21          1         1     1
19        22          1         1     1
20        39          1         1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get everything working using

df$group = as.integer(factor(df$first_column - 1:nrow(df)))